# "Locale failed to return region" when attempting to get top folders for a project

Tags: autodesk-forge

Our app allows users to select a file in the BIM 360, and as part of that we call the [GET top folders](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-topFolders-GET/) API to get the top folders within a project. For most projects this works, however for some the call occasionally fails, with the following error message:

```
{
  "developerMessage": "Locale failed to return region.",
  "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
  "errorCode": "403"
}
```

I read through the documentation linked there, and also searched for similar error messages, but I can't find any documentation on what this error means and what we might be missing from our request.

I also can't see any clear differences between these projects that do work and the ones that don't. It doesn't seem to matter who is calling the API, the same projects seem to fail when other members of my team try it with their credentials.

**How can we fix this problem so that we can call the API for these projects consistently?**

Comment: Could you help check if you selected the `BIM360 API` in your `https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps/{app_name}` page? ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/create-app/#step-2-register-an-app

Comment: Hm, good question. We haven't selected that API for that specific forge app. I'll add it to the forge app and check to see if the problem still happens.

Comment: We use a few different forge apps, and one was missing the BIM 360 API. I added it, and went through and tested with each app and they all seem to be working, but given it was an intermittent issue it might still resurface. I'll update if we run into it again.

Comment: Ok, feel free to get back if it persists.