# Flaky Responses From The Autodesk Data Management API when reading EMEA ACC projects and folders

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Currently, we are experiencing flaky api responses from the Autodesk Data Management API when trying to read projects and folders of EMEA ACC projects. This can happen at various levels, when getting projects, or top levels folders, or deeper in the folder structure.
Everything had been working smoothly until around the 29th of November when requests suddenly began to return a 500 Internal Error. Occasionly a request or two would work in a row before return to it's 500 error response behaviour. Of note on the Autodesk health checker is an issue with the Data Managemnet API from the 29th of November that is since marked solved. https://health.autodesk.com/history?filter=3139jd3z28ng

One thing of note is that when requests fail the `Content-Type` in the response header is returned as `text/html`. However, we are expecting `application/json` which is what is returned when the requests are successfully returned. Is there any information on this or is it a known problem on the Autodesk side of things? We have replicated this issue on different environments including the Autodesk VSCode extension.

Comment: Please share the x-request-id header on the response, that will help us track in our logs.

Comment: Hi Augusto,
thank you for your fast response.
We've now added the BIM360 API to our APS App, like suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775416/locale-failed-to-return-region-when-attempting-to-get-top-folders-for-a-projec
That seems to resolve the issue. We're still testing. Keep you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the BIM 360 API to the APS App resolves the issue.

See also:
["Locale failed to return region" when attempting to get top folders for a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775416/locale-failed-to-return-region-when-attempting-to-get-top-folders-for-a-projec)